# RedirectStandardOutput/Error from a Process to suppress it vs doing nothing

Tags: c#, process, io-redirection

I am running a process alongside my application to carry out various processing tasks. This process generates a lot of output to standard output and standard error that I do not care about. The process is being started as follows:

```
var p = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command, arguments)
            {
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            },
        EnableRaisingEvents = true
    };
p.Exited += OnProcessExited;
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

According to the documentation for the [RedirectStandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

> By setting RedirectStandardOutput to true to redirect the StandardOutput stream, you can manipulate or **suppress** the output of a process.

However there is no further information on that page about how one goes about suppressing the output.

My intention here is to redirect the output, begin the asynchronous read operation, but then do nothing with it. Essentially I am trying to achieve the same as redirecting to /dev/null, but I'm not sure what I am doing here is actually equivalent.

Is there any benefit to suppressing the output and is this the correct way to go about it?

Comment: It should be enough just set 'UseShellExecute' to false.
Console window shouldn't be create this way...